# How activate AMDGPU in Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Inspiron 5570

Tags: dell, amd-graphics, gpu-driver

Devices show:
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)

AND

Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445] (rev c1)
Subsystem: Dell Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
Kernel driver in use: amdgpu

Settings About shows:
Graphics: Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)

Software repository shows:
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu/bionic,now 18.0.1-1 amd64 [installed]
libdrm-amdgpu1/bionic,now 2.4.91-2 amd64 [installed]

In my search someone said that if it was using the AMD GPU, it would show on Settings-about.

I also saw that Ubuntu 16 was recently certified for Dell Inspiron 15 5000.

Q1: should Settings-about be showing the AMDGPU ?

Q2: is there a simple test app for graphics

Q3: AMD has an App on Windows 10 to adjust graphic parameters, how about Ubuntu ?

Comment: Following - looking to figure this same issue out for 20.10